# A value of type 'Null' can't be returned from the method 'onGenerateRoute' because it has a return type of 'Route<dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

Actually I was trying to add genearatedRoute but i was facing this error
A value of type 'Null' can't be returned from the method 'onGenerateRoute' because it has a return type of 'Route'
Below is my code

```
class AppRouter {
   Route onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings routeSettings) {
    switch (routeSettings.name) {
      case '/':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const SplashScreen());
        break;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, can you add more code please ? Like, where your method onGenerateRoute is called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below code fixed the issue for me

```
class AppRouter {
  Route? onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings routeSettings) {
    switch (routeSettings.name) {
      case '/':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const SplashScreen());
        break;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you shouldn't return **null**, you must return a **MaterialPageRoute** in every state. You can define a default page like an empty container or an error page to display in unknown routeSettings.

```
class AppRouter {
  Route onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings routeSettings) {
   switch (routeSettings.name) {
    case '/':
     return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const SplashScreen());
     break;
    default:
     return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Scaffold(body: Container(),),);
   }
  }
}
```

I hope it could help you.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have null returning in default, and you must return Route object from function. To properly fix it, maybe in default option specify route to home screen.